# Как найти все команды в памяти процесса, с определенной сигнатурой?

Tags: ассемблер, дизассемблирование

Известен адрес, он записан в переменную ассемблера, пример, `unk_7FF67EEFE300`.
Как сформировать опкоды для такой команды `lea rcx, unk_7FF67EEFE300`, чтобы затем, по побайтовой сигнатуре уже найти все подобные команды в памяти процесса.

Comment: lea загружает адрес самой переменной, а не адрес _из переменной_. проще всего, создайте программу из одной инструкции `lea rcx, [0x123456789ABCDEF0]` посмотрите опкоды которые сделал на нее ассемблер и просто подставьте нужный вам адрес из переменной на место 123...

Comment: Я смотрю опкод, пример, ```4C 8D 0D 01 C6 4F 01```, там нет адреса, получается это каким-то образом отсылка к переменной, и я не понимаю как.

Comment: А вы ассемблировали именно с фиксированным адресом или перемеренную подставили ? Если переменную, то в инструкции адрес самой переменной, а не тот, что в ней содержится

Comment: Тут мне подсказали, что в x64 в операнде будет смещение, а не сам адрес, вот теперь бы разобраться как его сформировать

Comment: Ну чудес не бывает, адрес в любом случае должен быть как то вычислен. специальной базы для этого вроде нет. Если дополнительных префиксов нет, то REX.W префикс (4C) говорит, что используется 64 битный адрес (если программа для long mode) (И расширенный регистр). Вы ассемблировали именно 0x123... и при этом получили 0D 01 и т.п. или все таки что то другое ассемблировали ?

Comment: Не, не, это пример опкодов другой команды, для вашей команды получилось вот что ```48 8D 0C 25 F0 DE BC 9A``` Адрес мне известен! А вот как получить из него опкод...

Comment: Любопытно, yasm мне дал предупреждение, что операнд не влезает в 32 бита, значит он не готов кодировать 64 ... тогда я что то не понимаю ... У вас после 9A следующий байт точно относится к следующей инструкции (или его вообще нет), там случайно где то остаток 78 56 и т.п. не лежат ?

Comment: Предупреждение nasm мне тоже выдал ```warning: dword data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]```

Comment: Ну IDA показывает такие опкоды на эту команду ```48 8D 0C 25 F0 DE BC 9A```

Comment: Ну я начал въезжать про то, что пишут в описании REX префикса. Играет роль еще MOD/RM байт, который у нас в данном случае 25. он оканчивается на 0101, что говорит о том, что адрес задан относительно текущего RIP. Так написано в описании, НО я закодировал подряд две LEA на одну переменную и получил одинаковое смещение в обоих командах, так что это никак не может быть текущий RIP. В общем чего то я еще не понимаю, узнать бы чего ...

Comment: Но если все таки там кодируется так, как написано в доке, то у вас проблема, по сигнатуре искать бесполезно, потому что сигнатура зависит от смещения команды в сегменте кода ...

Comment: А почему бесполезно? Адрес то в памяти мне известен, я сканирую память побайтово, значит знаю его.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70763/discussion-between-arvitaly-and-mike).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Адресовать конкретную область памяти в инструкции LEA можно множеством способов. И так же множеством способов можно достичь конкретного адреса. Но только в пределах разумного, Intel не предусмотрела в системе команд 64-битного режима возможности обратиться по произвольному 64-битному адресу, указанному непосредственно в команде. Обращаться можно только по произвольному адресу, находящемуся в регистре или по 32-битному смещению, относительно какого либо 64-битного регистра (а так же суммы 2х регистров с умножением одного из них на 1,2,4,8).

Описание правил кодирования инструкций можно посмотреть [тут](http://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding), а так же разъяснить некоторые непонятные после прочтения вики моменты, [тут](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/bpetkov-x86-hacks.pdf)

Для начала вы должны определиться где у вас в программе храниться база, относительно которой можно задать такое 32-битное смещение, что бы достичь нужного адреса. В комментариях вы привели пример команды `4C 8D 0D 01 C6 4F 01`, она декодируется следующим образом:

```
4C REX-префикс: WRXB=1100. W=1 используются 64-битные операнды.
                           R=1 первый бит поля modrm.reg
8D OPCODE инструкции LEA
0D modrm-байт: mod=00 reg=001 rm=101
   первый операнд в lea - регистр,
   rex.r-modrm.reg=1.001 - регистр R9
   rex.b-modrm.rm =0.101 - RIP+disp32
014FC601 - смещение относительно регистра RIP
```

Итого вы привели пример команды `LEA R9, [RIP+0x014FC601]`. Если вы хотите сделать `LEA RCX,...` так же относительно регистра RIP, то ваша команда будет отличаться только одним битом в REX-префиксе, он будет равен 0x48. Но далеко не факт, что исследуемая вами программа будет адресовать нужную область именно относительно RIP, а следовательно все поля могут быть совершенно иными и смещение может рассчитываться относительно другого регистра.